# Pandas json_normalize on recursively nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas, recursion

I have a json file with a deeply nested recursive structure:

```
{"children": [ 
              "val" = x
              "data" = y
              "children": [{ 
                           "val" = x
                           "data" = y
                           "children": [{ 
                                         ....
              "val" = x
              "data" = y
              "children": [{ 
                           "val" = x
                           "data" = y
                           "children": [{ 
                                         ....
```

Using pandas [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) as follows:

```
json_normalize(data = self.data["children"], record_path="children")
```

gives dataframe where the first level is flattened but the deepers levels remain json strings within the dataframe.

How can i flatten my dataframe such that the entire json tree is unpacked and flattened?

Comment: keep repeating it until it stops working...

Answer (score 0):

Providing your json is well formatted and has the same structure at all levels you can extract all the data by passing a **List** of keywords to json_normalize from each level.

```
json = {'children': [{
          'val': 1,
          'data': 2,
          'children': [{
                       'val': 3,
                       'data' : 4,
                       'children': [{'val' : 4,
                                     'data' : 5}],
                       }],
          },{
          'val' : 6,
          'data' : 7,
          'children': [{
                       'val' : 8,
                       'data' : 9,
                       'children': [{'val' : 10,
                                     'data' : 11}],
                       }]
          }]}

for i in range(1,3):
    print( json_normalize(data = json,record_path=['children']*i) )
```

This gives the following output, which you can use recursively add into a single **DataFrame** if you wish.

```
                                            children  data  val
0  [{'val': 3, 'data': 4, 'children': [{'val': 4,...     2    1
1  [{'val': 8, 'data': 9, 'children': [{'val': 10...     7    6
                    children  data  val
0    [{'val': 4, 'data': 5}]     4    3
1  [{'val': 10, 'data': 11}]     9    8
   data  val
0     5    4
1    11   10
```